# Cron Job Run Only Once

Tags: php, cronjob

I set a cron job in CPanel , I am using hostinger, but it only run once even though I scheduled it to run twice in an hour, what may be the problem?

```
**Time**            **Command To Run**

0 0,12 * * *          /usr/bin/wget /URL
```

Comment: Twice in an hour or twice a day? It's `min * hour * day/month * month * weekday`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35575322/1161309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to run a cron job twice an hour is:

> **#minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week command**
>
> 1,31 * * * * command

As @jnL says your are running it twice a day, at 0:00 and 12:00.

Comment: Or any other time like xx:15 and xx:45 ;) Or more periodically: `*/30` for every 30 minutes

Comment: You're right, I've only used question example. Thank you for completing the answer!

Comment: What if it says 0 * * * *?

Comment: It will run the command once an hour at :00. Also, you can do it 0,30, it was only an example.